# SHT30 activating Fan control

Tags: esp8266

I've a working hardware setup and two codes 1 to read the sht30 and push the data to my tft screen.

And 2 a code to set a fan (2fans) on and off.

I want to combine these whenever the humidity is over 50% the fans should go on.

3 issues arise.

1. less important my serial.println() doesn't print anything anymore
2. my second if loop doesn't get printed not in serial or in display
3. Fans are not getting activated by the code.

My searching leads me to think I need to convert my sht30.humidity into an int before making the if loop.

Or it could be something entirely else ofcourse.

```
#include <WEMOS_SHT3X.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>



Adafruit_SSD1306 display(1);
#if (SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT != 32)
#error("Height incorrect, please fix Adafruit_SSD1306.h!");
#endif


SHT3X sht30(0x45);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  // initialize with the I2C addr 0x3C
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("start");
  // Clear the buffer.
  display.clearDisplay();
}

void loop() {


 // Clear the buffer.
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);

  if(sht30.get()==0)
  {
    display.setCursor(35, 10);
    display.println("T: ");
    display.setCursor(50, 10);
    display.println(sht30.cTemp);
    display.setCursor(35, 20);
    display.println("H: ");
    display.setCursor(50, 20);
    display.println(sht30.humidity);
  }
  else
  {
    display.setCursor(35, 10);
    display.println("Error!");
    Serial.println("error");
  }
  display.display();
  delay(1000);

  Hcheck();
  Serial.println("checking humidity");






}

void Hcheck() {
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("============ Check Humidity ===============");
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(35, 10);
  display.println(sht30.humidity);
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(sht30.humidity);

  if(sht30.humidity <= 50 ) {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setCursor(35, 20);
    display.display();
    delay(500);
  }else {
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Air is dry");

  }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the I2C communication works? You can check, if the lines are HIGH most of the time. If one of them is constant low, the problem is a stuck I2C bus

Comment: are you saying that `start` does not print when you reset the ESP8266?

Comment: If my sht30 works and the tft screen works I2C must work correct? It's the pwm signal that doesn't work. @jsotola Nope not a single serialprintln works so I guess something else is wrong here...?

Comment: put `Serial.print("start");` right after `Serial.begin` .... try to narrow down where the program hangs up